# What types of model files does Tensorflow support and how to load .ckpt + .pb

Tags: tensorflow

I found TensorFlow supports various of model files, `.ckpt, .meta, .pb`

1) now I have a resnet50 model, with `.ckpt` 102MB and `.pb` 459KB, how to load them into memory by using TensorFlow?

2) And how many types of model files does Tensorflow support? Could anyone provide a list or material like (such as 1. ckpt+pb 2. frozen.pb 3. meta + ??)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files are not different file types to store complete models. Each contains different information and collectively they store a single model.

The `.meta` file stores the bulk of the structure of the model, while the `.ckpt` file is a checkpoint file storing information about the values of the Variables within the network (weights and biases for a neural network) at a stage of training where the network was saved. The `.pb` files are protocol buffer files.

To see a working example of how to save and restore a model using these files see here:

https://bitbucket.org/FinleyGibson/save-and-load-tf-model/

and open the .ipynb files with the jupyter notebook file viewer

Comment: According to TensorFlow official doc, there is 1) `.pb` storing graph definitions, 2) `variables` folder (seems the same usage of `.ckpt`) so `.meta` seems to be the same thing with `.pb` but just with different format? And also frozen_graph.pb could store variables but there are few docs about this?